# PolicyVerificationInInterceptor Inbound policy verification failed: These policy alternatives can not be satisfied WSS4J + CXF Client

Tags: cxf, webservice-client, policy, wss4j

I'm implementing **web service client** in Java which uses Apache **CXF 3.1.1 + wss4j 2.2.1** for WS-Security running in **JBOSS EAP 6.3** environment.

I've setted following properties in **WSS4JInInterceptor** for signature verification in the following way:

```
org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client client =  org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.getClient(service);
org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Endpoint cxfEndpoint = client.getEndpoint();

Map<String,Object> inProps = new HashMap<String,Object>();

inProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION,WSHandlerConstants.SIGNATURE + " " + WSHandlerConstants.TIMESTAMP + " ");
inProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIG_PROP_FILE, merlin.properties");
inProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.DEC_PROP_FILE, "merlin.properties");
WSS4JInInterceptor wssIn = new WSS4JInInterceptor(inProps);

cxfEndpoint.getInInterceptors().add(wssIn);
try {
result = call service...
}
```

**In this way I got this exception:
[org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyVerificationInInterceptor] Inbound policy verification failed: These policy alternatives can not be satisfied:**

```
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}AsymmetricBinding
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}InitiatorToken
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}X509Token
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}WssX509V3Token10
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}RecipientToken
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}AlgorithmSuite
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}Basic128
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}Layout
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}Strict
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}IncludeTimestamp
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}OnlySignEntireHeadersAndBody
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}SignedParts
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}SupportingTokens
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}WssX509v3Token10
```

**The policy section of the wsdl exposed server-side is below:**

```
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="ExamplePolicy">
<sp:AsymmetricBinding>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:InitiatorToken>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/Once">
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:WssX509V3Token10/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:X509Token>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:InitiatorToken>
<sp:RecipientToken>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/Once">
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:WssX509V3Token10/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:X509Token>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:RecipientToken>
<sp:AlgorithmSuite>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:Basic128/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:AlgorithmSuite>
<sp:Layout>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:Strict/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:Layout>
<sp:IncludeTimestamp/>
<sp:OnlySignEntireHeadersAndBody/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:AsymmetricBinding>
<sp:SignedParts>
<sp:Body/>
</sp:SignedParts>
<sp:SupportingTokens>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/Never">
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:WssX509v3Token10/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:X509Token>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:SupportingTokens>
</wsp:Policy>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the non-policy aware WSS4JInInterceptor class. You need to use the PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor class instead. Note that this is configured differently to the WSS4JInInterceptor. See here: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-securitypolicy.html

Comment: Thanks for the help.

As you have suggested, I'm using now the
org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor passing this property:

ctx.put(SecurityConstants.SIGNATURE_PROPERTIES, "merlin.properties");


Now I got this exception:
These policy alternatives can not be satisfied: 
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}WssX509v3Token10